# How to get the actorRef of the failing actor in a OneForOneStrategy setup?

Tags: scala, akka

How can I get the actorRef or name of the failing node? I need to restart the node if the exception happens once. If the exception happens > 1, then I need to resume.

My thought was to have the supervisor store how many times a given node has had the exception - but I can't figure out which node failed. Maybe the approach is bad.

x would be the count of times the failing node had a given exception.

```
 OneForOneStrategy() {
     case _: FileNotFoundException =>
         // Need to know how many times node n has had this exception and restart/resume as required.
         if(x == 1)
             Restart
         else
             Resume
     case _: Exception => Stop
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the `FileNotFoundException` and throw a `CustomException` that has an ActorRef field set to the excepting Actor (self).  Then in your OneForOne, you catch the `CustomException` that has the `ActorRef` field set to the problem actor.  So now you have a reference to the failing actor, then check the exception count as you described inside your supervisor and make the call on whether or not to restart/resume.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in supervisor's Decider you can obtain the failing child's ActorRef via sender() method.